# Cropping of PNG image

Tags: png

I found a strange behaviour with some PNG images. On cropping the image, using MS Paint, the interlace type(in IHDR) is getting changed from 1 to 0.

Can any one confirm is it normal behavior or is it some problem in the cropping algorithm??

If it is a normal behaviour, how is interlace type of an image judged??

Comment: And how is this about programming? You're asking about the behaviour of MS paint when editing a specific format of image. StackOverflow is not the place to be asking this.

Comment: @enhzflep Its not only about MS paint. Through whatever application I crop a PNG image and then try to decode, I am facing the problem of interlace bit getting changed.

Comment: And again, how is this a programming question? It's about general computer hardware or software. It does not belong here. This site is specifically for programming questions, I assert that this question is not one. You may do better on the StackExchange site SuperUser. I'm currently using a program that does not have this limitation. It's freely downloadable for Win, Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

When the image is interlaced it is split up into 7 passes of data. In order to display and crop, all seven passes have to be combined first.

When you crop a PNG image, you are creating a brand new image. MS Paint can do whatever it wants (or you tell it) in creating the new image. The easy thing is for it to create the new image with one pass (0=no interlace) rather than to divide the image data into the 7 passes again.

This change is not inherent in cropping. Interlacing is a choice of the encoder (usually specified by the user/caller).